# GKE - GPU nvidia - cuda drivers dont work

Tags: gpu, pytorch, google-kubernetes-engine, nvidia

I have setup a kubernetes node with a nvidia tesla k80 and followed [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus) to try to run a pytorch docker image with nvidia drivers and cuda drivers working.

I have managed to install the nvidia daemonsets and i can now see the following pods:

```
nvidia-driver-installer-gmvgt
nvidia-gpu-device-plugin-lmj84
```

The problem is that even while using the recommendend image `nvidia/cuda:10.0-runtime-ubuntu18.04` i still can't find the nvidia drivers inside my pod:

```
root@pod-name-5f6f776c77-87qgq:/app# ls /usr/local/
bin  cuda  cuda-10.0  etc  games  include  lib  man  sbin  share  src
```

But the tutorial mention:

> CUDA libraries and debug utilities are made available inside the container at `/usr/local/nvidia/lib64` and `/usr/local/nvidia/bin`, respectively.

I have also tried to test if cuda was working through `torch.cuda.is_available()` but i get False as a return value.

Many help in advance for your help

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an exact copy of https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/9738/210

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so i finally made nvidia drivers work.

It is mandatory to set a ressource limit to access the nvidia driver, which is weird considering either way my pod was on the right node with the nvidia drivers installed..

This made the nvidia folder accessible, but im'still unable to make the cuda install work with pytorch 1.3.0 .. [ [issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58770347/gke-unable-to-make-cuda-work-with-pytorch) ]

Comment: Wow. Yep. That was it. Thanks!